# loading data into vuex store before app loads, how to accomplish this?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I am making a dispatch call to my store inside the `created` hook of `App.vue`, in a child component I then ask for that with a `getter`, the issue seems to be that when loading the app the child component is loaded *before* the data has been placed in the store and does not display. I am confident about this from the fact that I console logged and the first log is the child component who is the consumer of the store. How can I guarantee that the `dispatch` which is needed site wide happens before any other components are loaded?

---

// App.vue

```
created() {
       this.$store.dispatch(this.$mts.diseases.DISEASES_LIST) //note I tried with async/await to no avail
    ...
```

//child component

```
created() {
      this.diseases = this.$store.getters.diseasesList
    ...
```

As noted I tried to make the code inside the App.vue asyn but it seems that's it's not loading first so this did not help.

Answer (score 3):

You should put the property inside a computed in your child component, that way it will populate as soon as the value exists in your store

```
computed: {
    diseases () {
        return this.$store.getters.diseasesList
    }
}
```

[See the VueX docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#property-style-access)

If you want to wait for the data to be available before loading the component then you can use `v-if` [see docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if)

```
<your-component v-if="$store.getters.diseasesList">
    ...
</your-component>
```

Comment: I don't like that solution so much, I should be able to load data onto my app on initial load and only then load everything else, why would a child component be loading _before_ the `created` hook on `App.vue`

Comment: You can stop child components from loading by using `v-if` and wait for the value to be populated. I'll update the answer

Comment: I could but that's a workaround, there should be a way to actually determine what loads before what.

Comment: The child component won't attempt to load unless the `v-if` condition is truthy so it is a good way to determine what order things load in. I agree it feels a bit weird at first.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Nuxt.js (https://nuxtjs.org/) it has `fetch` and `asyncData` support out of the box, so that component won't render before the promises they return are solved.